# Recommended git setup for multiple servers

Tags: git, unix, bitbucket

I'm currently reading up on Git through ProGit and am covering the branching section (chapter 3). The reason I'm interested in using git altogether is because I have a core of MATLAB and Python code which, for computational reasons, is spread across multiple UNIX clusters and I simply cannot keep track of the different versions by simple copying and pasting. 
For that reason, I have a private BitBucket repo and I want to make it such that the code is effectively shared between the clusters.

The MATLAB / Python core is something I want to keep up to date, perhaps on my server's master branch. The only thing that might change across clusters is wrapper shell scripts that organize compute node jobs that run the code core. Some servers are Torque / MAUI - based, so they need utilities such as `qsub`, while others are SLURM-based, so they need scripts such as `sbatch`. In addition, because the different clusters have different hardware configurations which point towards different methods of parallelization, I also expect there to be a slightly different directory structure on every cluster. For example, in one of the servers I am limited to 4 jobs being able to be submitted simultaneously, while on the other server there is no limit (well, no limit for the stuff that I want to do anyway). Without delving too much into the details, this changes the directory structure of my input data and consequently changes the filesystem names that my shell scripts read from (and to).

Based on this information, what would people think is the best possible branching setup for me? Should I make one separate server branch for every cluster that I have access to? Should I stick to one master branch and aggressively merge with it every single time I make a change on one of my clusters? Please keep in mind that this situation, where I'm the only contributor in this project, is **very unlikely** to change.

Comment: could you create one repo (with master/develop/feautere-x branch) of  `cluster-project` with the source that works on all projects?  maybe you only need a build-script, eg. Makefile, for those adjustements over separeate git repos, like `cluster-project-extras-qsub` and `cluster-project-extras-sbatch`? Or could the `cluster-project` share code, eg. through gitmodules?

Comment: I'm not sure what `gitmodules` is just yet, since I'm a beginner in this VCS, so I will respond to the previous part of the comment; Yes, it is possible that I have a branch that only contains the code that works across all clusters (I'm assuming that you ment to say "branch" instead of "repo"). In that case, I would essentially only push changes on the core code on that particular branch. I'm not sure what you are suggesting when it comes to the build script thought; are you suggesting that I have one branch per cluster? (I know what a Makefile is, I'm just somewhat confused.)

Comment: i just thought about keeping it simple (8-{)}, like one branch, one main repo (that holds the shared source) and one build script for the difference builds ... to keep maintenance simple as possible. I don't know your project, but i would even prefer a preprocessor than many branches, thinking of merge/rebase of feature-x or  the bug-x.